# Evaluating a series with the Möbius function and greatest common divisor.

Tags: number-theory, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, euler-product

> **Problem:**  Let $\gcd(a,b,c,d)$ refer to the largest integer $r$ such that $r$ divides each of $a,b,c,d$.  Evaluate the series $$\sum_{a=1}^{\infty}\sum_{b=1}^{\infty}\sum_{c=1}^{\infty}\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)\mu(c)\mu(d)}{a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}d^{2}}\gcd(a,b,c,d)^{4},$$ where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function.

I tried several tricks, but I eventually got stuck.  I think it should be possible to rewrite the entire thing as an Euler Product. It looks very similar to 
the double series $$\sum_{a=1}^{\infty}\sum_{b=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)}{a^{2}b^{2}}\gcd(a,b)^{2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}.$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you rewrite the double sum as an Euler product?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, the double sum equals $\frac{6}{\pi^2}=\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}$ which is just $\prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$.

Comment: That's cheating. You can write pretty much any number as an Euler product. If you didn't know the double sum came to $6/\pi^2$, could you write it as an Euler product?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That is how you get $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ in the first place.  In general, if you have infinite series with multiplicative functions, and it evaluates to something with the zeta function, it is almost always by using Euler products.

Comment: OK, so what you're saying is that you can twiddle the double sum into an Euler product, but the same techniques don't work for the 4-fold sum. Are you able to get a good numerical estimate of the 4-fold sum and then check to see if it seems to be a simple combination of some Euler products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sum can be re-written in terms of an Euler product:

$$\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\sum_{c=1}^\infty\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)\mu(c)\mu(d)}{a^2b^2c^2d^2}\gcd(a,b,c,d)^4=\frac{1296}{\pi^8}\prod_{p}(1+\frac{p^4-1}{(p^2-1)^4})\approx .16544\cdots$$

---

A proof can be given as follows:

First note that,

$$d\mid x_1\wedge d\mid x_2\wedge d\mid x_3\wedge d\mid x_4\iff d\mid \gcd(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$$

So we get:$$\sum_{d=1}^\infty f(d)1_{d\mid x_1}1_{d\mid x_2}1_{d\mid x_3}1_{d\mid x_4}=\sum_{d=1}^\infty f(d)1_{d\mid x_1\wedge d\mid x_2\wedge d\mid x_3\wedge d\mid x_4}=\sum_{d=1}^\infty f(d)1_{d\mid \gcd(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)}$$
$$=\sum_{d\mid \gcd(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)}f(d)$$

Where $1_{A}=[A]$ in Iverson bracket notation

Then define:

$$\phi_s(n)=n^s\prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^s})$$

So that we have: $(\phi_s*1)(n)=n^s$

Now set $f=\phi_4$ in the aforementioned equality and we get that:

$$\sum_{d=1}^\infty \phi_4(d)1_{d\mid x_1}1_{d\mid x_2}1_{d\mid x_3}1_{d\mid x_4}=\gcd(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^4$$

Now we note that:

$$\sum_{x_i=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(x_i)}{x_i^2}1_{d\mid x_i}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(dn)}{(dn)^2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{\mu(d)}{\phi_2(d)}$$

Then multiplying both sides of the previous series by $\frac{\mu(x_1)}{x_1^2}\frac{\mu(x_2)}{x_2^2}\frac{\mu(x_3)}{x_3^2}\frac{\mu(x_4)}{x_4^2}$ and rearranging gives:

$$\sum_{d=1}^\infty \phi_4(d)(\frac{\mu(x_1)}{x_1^2}1_{d\mid x_1})(\frac{\mu(x_2)}{x_2^2}1_{d\mid x_2})(\frac{\mu(x_3)}{x_3^2}1_{d\mid x_3})(\frac{\mu(x_4)}{x_4^2}1_{d\mid x_4})$$
$$=\frac{\mu(x_1)\mu(x_2)\mu(x_3)\mu(x_4)}{x_1^2x_2^2x_3^2x_4^2}\gcd(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^4$$

Thus:

$$\sum_{x_1=1}^\infty\sum_{x_2=1}^\infty\sum_{x_3=1}^\infty\sum_{x_4=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(x_1)\mu(x_2)\mu(x_3)\mu(x_4)}{x_1^2x_2^2x_3^2x_4^2}\gcd(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^4$$

$$=(\frac{6}{\pi^2})^4\sum_{d=1}^\infty \phi_4(d)\frac{\mu(d)^4}{\phi_2(d)^4}=\frac{1296}{\pi^8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\phi_4(n)}{\phi_2(n)^4}|\mu(n)|=\frac{1296}{\pi^8}\prod_{p}(1+\frac{\phi_4(p)}{\phi_2(p)^4})$$

So we have:

$$\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\sum_{c=1}^\infty\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)\mu(c)\mu(d)}{a^2b^2c^2d^2}\gcd(a,b,c,d)^4=\frac{1296}{\pi^8}\prod_{p}(1+\frac{p^4-1}{(p^2-1)^4})$$

A similar argument will give your second sum as $\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(a)\mu(b)}{a^2b^2}\gcd(a,b)^2=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

In addition to formula for other such similar generalizations.

Comment: As an update to readers on the status of this answer: (a) Ethan has informed me that the strange `b`s are in fact `k`s, and (b) I have pointed out an issue in going from the last line of the first image to the first line of the second image: $(a,b,c,d,k)=1$ does not entail $$\mu(ak)\mu(bk)\mu(ck)\mu(dk)=\mu(a)\mu(b)\mu(c)\mu(d)\mu(k)^4.$$ (Counterexample: $a=2,b=3,c=5,d=7,k=2$.) It is possible a symmetry argument however can show that these counterexamples' contributions to the sum cancel each other out.

Comment: @anon Fixed, this is an entirely new solution.